# Iphone Application working fine with IOS 5.1 not running properly with IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

The iphone Application working fine with the IOS 5.1 but after upgrading XCode 4.5 with IOS6 it is displaying only splash screen and than blank in simulator. Application is not crashing and getting lots of deprecation warnings(Mostly due to presentModalViewController and dismissModalViewController). Please Suggest.

Comment: i would suggest looking at those warnings

Comment: What warnings are you getting? Have you tried NSLogging until where you are getting successfully in your application?

Comment: Now I am not getting splash screen and getting error: failed to attach to process ID 0 in console

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering how to fix the warnings you're getting about the `presentModalViewController`, here's what my updated version of the code looks like:

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note that `presentModalViewController` was renamed to exclude the `Modal` part, and note that `completion:nil` was added.

After you resolve all of the warnings, try again.  My guess is that your issue will be resolved.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot when transiting a XCode 4.x project to XCode 4.5.
The workaround can be quite simple!

To have your app running, you should clean all previous build information.

To do so, in XCode 4.5, go to `Product > Clean`. Then try and run your app.

If it is not sufficient, press the "`Alt`" key and click on `Product > Clean Build Folder`.

Hope that helps.

Edit: this will not solve the deprecation issues (the `presentModalViewController` now comes with the `completion:` argument in iOS6) but will quite certainly solve the `error: failed to attach to process ID 0` issue!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if there is a problem with `presentModalViewController` and you are presenting something at launch, that might be why its not showing.

Deal with the warnings and see what happens.